# My F1 US visa interview went wrong. Could you please suggest how to improve?

Tags: usa, visa-refusals, f1-visas

Below is my conversation with the Visa Officer (VO). I tried to recreate the conversation as best as I could remember. I have another appointment for the visa interview in a week. Please help me improve any aspect that I might have done wrong. Thanks a lot!

> Me: Hello, Good Morning?
>   VO: Good Morning, pass the i20 and Passport please!
>   Me: Here you go.
>   VO: Georgia Institute of Technology! Personal Funds! So, how are you going to manage this much money?
>   Me: I have 134,000 dollars in my accounts. Moreover, my father can provide any further expenses that might occur.
>   VO: In which account?
>   Me: In multiple accounts.
>   VO: How did you get this much money?
>   Me: Well most of the money is from my mother's savings, that I got after she passed away from cancer 7 years ago, as I am the only child.
>   VO: How did your mother get this money? What did she do?
>   Me: Well most of the money is from mother's saving….
>   VO: Yeah, I know, but how did she get it?
>   Me: Well my mother used to run a private medical school, alongside my father, who is a government doctor and some of his colleagues. There, primary health care was taught to students who enrolled in the program…
>   VO: Typing for a while…..
>   Me: Waiting
>   VO: Typing…..
>   Me: Should I show you my account statements?
>   VO: uhmm.. No need.
>   Me: Okay...
>   VO: Typing…..
>   Me: *waiting*
>   Me: Can I add something?
>   VO: Go ahead.
>   Me: My father works as a government doctor. Presently he is posted as Assistant Director, for the Ministry of Health, Government of Bangladesh. He also has a private practice.
>   VO: Typing…
>   VO: Sir, … how did you get here today?
>   Me: By car.
>   VO: Is that your car? Do you own that car?
>   Me: No, I rented that car.
>   VO: Oh! You rented that car! Okay.
>   Me: *dumbfounded*
>   VO: *Typing for a while again. Hands me the white leaflet.*  Sorry Sir, you do not qualify for the visa you have applied for. Have a good day!
>   Me: Thank you sir.

Comment: What's the clause/code that is written on your refusal letter?

Comment: In Bangladesh, they either hand you the "blue pamphlet", which is the approval one. Or they hand you the white one which is the rejected one. The cause is always 214b, white one. This is true for F1 visas here.

Comment: You have $134K, which means you have at least 11 Million of your Bangladeshi currency and you rented a car for an interview? Do you think that matches up for a sharp eyed interviewer?

Comment: Yes. I understood that, but I didn't want to lie at that moment. We live in a different city and my father's car is there. I have just joined a job 8 months ago, before which I was a student in this city. I never felt the need to own a car in Dhaka where you can walk faster and I lived on campus. Is there a way I could've handled it better?